# MySQL - multiple GROUP_CONCATs on the same field

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query that does a LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT from two tables:

```
t1
authId |  tagId
----------------
      1|      10
      1|      11
      2|      12
      2|      13
      2|      14

t2
tagId  |  type   |  value
--------------------------
     10|  skill  |   RNA
     11|  skill  |   seq
     12|  skill  |   cells
     13|  certi  |   cert1
     14|  certi  |   cert2
```

Running

```
SELECT t1.authId, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.value SEPARATOR ',') as skills
          FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 on t2.id = t1.tagId  
          WHERE type = 'skill'        
          GROUP BY t1.authId;
```

works and gives me:

```
authId | skills
---------------
      1| RNA,seq
      2| cells
```

I want to expand to other types like this:

```
authId | skills  | certi
------------------------
      1| RNA,seq |
      2| cells   | cert1,cert2
```

I'm trying to do it by adding a WHERE clause inside my GROUP_CONCAT, but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

It could be performed with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.authId, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `type` = 'skill' THEN t2.value END SEPARATOR ',') as skills,
   GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `type` = 'certi' THEN t2.value END SEPARATOR ',') as certi
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t2.id = t1.tagId  
-- WHERE type IN ('skill', 'certi')        
GROUP BY t1.authId;
```

Comment: This is an inner join

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, as long as we filter in `WHERE`.